# Authorization with token in guzzlehttp Laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, microservices, guzzle

I'm trying to make a request with my other endpoint, using GuzzleHttp in laravel, but the token isn't authorizing it. I believe it's in the way I'm going. Anyone know how to fix this? This is my code.

```
public function productRecommendation($rowPerPage,$keywords, $page){

        try{
            $request = request();
            $token = $request->bearerToken();
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $promise = $client->request('GET', $this->sellerUrl.'recommended', [
                'headers'  =>  ['Authorization' => "Bearer {$token}"],
                'query' =>
                    [
                        'rowPerPage' => $rowPerPage,
                        'page' => $page,
                        'keywords' => $keywords,
                    ],
            ]);
            $response = (string) $promise->getBody();
            return json_decode($response, true);
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            return $e;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the bearer token of your first application using `$request->bearerToken()` and send it  to  your second application for authorization which must not work;

You need to get a working token from your second application. You can either generate a token in your second application and copy it inside your current `$token` variable, or first call the `login` endpoint of second application with your credentials and use that token.

By the way, Laravel now supports a guzzle wrapper called `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http` which makes things lot easier, you can rewrite your code like this:

```php
public function productRecommendation($rowPerPage, $keywords, $page)
{
    try{
        $token = "some valid token from second endpoint";

        $response = Http::withToken(
            $token
        )->get(
            $this->sellerUrl . 'recommended',
            [
                'rowPerPage' => $rowPerPage,
                'page' => $page,
                'keywords' => $keywords,
            ]
        );

        return response()->json(
            json_decode($response->body(), true)
        );
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        return $e;
    }
}
```